# How do I construct a Platypus script to open a file in emacs from the finder?

Tags: osx, openwith

I am trying to use [Platypus](https://sveinbjorn.org/platypus) to wrap a bash script to open a file in emacs using emacsclient.

The script that I am using looks like:

```
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/emacsclient -n -c "$@"
```

When I associate a file (using it to open org-mode files from DevonThink) to the new Platypus created app, emacs fires right up, but it opens the *scratch* buffer rather than a buffer with the file contents.

The above script does work when invoked from the command line.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I don't know osx dev nor Platpus. How the file can be passed as command-linne arguments to your script? GUI apps don't have the concept of command-line args, since they aren't CLI apps. If my guess are correct, $@ in your script is always empty.

Comment: hi, @xuchunyang .. Platypus is a program that wraps a script as an application. Part of the functionality is consuming command line arguments.

Comment: Then are you sure your script does get the filename as arguments? It seems emacsclient doesn't get the filename according to your description. You can try to debug your script by logging $@, e.g., `echo "$@" > /tmp/log`.

Comment: yes, I monitored the output, and nothing is coming back. I think it might be a platypus issue